# slideUp() and slideDown() using jQuery

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

Hi Friend I want to make a simple slideUP and slideDown by clicking on a div but thing is when is lick on the div its slide down but when i click again on div to make it slideUp it again slide down.. pleas help me guys You can **[check fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DcWS2/600/)**  or you can check code below

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var h = $(".slide").height();

    var h = h-15;
    alert(h);
    $(".slide").css('top','-'+h+'px')

    //var r=0, dir=true;
    $(".slide").click(function() {
        //dir = !dir;
       // r = dir? -280 : 0;

        if($(".slide").css('top','-'+h+'px'))
        {
        $(this).stop().animate({top: h+'px'}, 800);
        } else

        {
            $(this).stop().animate({top: '-'+h+'px'}, 800);
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.slide {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:-102px;
    left:0px;
    background-color:#8cc;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slide">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.
</div>

<div style="width:350px; background:#ccc;">
    Slide demo<br/>
    Slide demo<br/>
    Slide demo<br/>
    Slide demo<br/>
    Slide demo<br/>
    Slide demo<br/>
    Slide demo<br/>
    Slide demo<br/>
    Slide demo<br/>
    Slide demo<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Answers below work but this is really easy as already in jQuery library check out https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: Oh I see you don't want it to be completely hidden as you want user to click on the div rather than another control

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var h = $(".slide").height();

    var h = h-15;

    $(".slide").css('top','-'+h+'px')

    //var r=0, dir=true;
    $(".slide").click(function() {
        //dir = !dir;
       // r = dir? -280 : 0;

        if($(".slide").css('top')==-h+'px')
        {
        $(this).stop().animate({top: h+'px'}, 800);
        } else

        {
            $(this).stop().animate({top: '-'+h+'px'}, 800);
        }
    });
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/DcWS2/602/**

Answer (score 1):

You could give the element a data attribute like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="slide" data-slide="true">
```

**jQuery**

```
  $(".slide").click(function () {
        if ($(this).data('slide')) {//checked if true
            $(this).stop().animate({
                top: h + 'px'
            }, 800);
            $(this).data('slide', false);
        } else {
            $(this).data('slide', true);
            $(this).stop().animate({
                top: '-' + h + 'px'
            }, 800);
        }
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DcWS2/601/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace `if($(".slide").css('top','-'+h+'px'))` with this: `if($(".slide").css('top') == '-'+h+'px')`

Answer (score 0):

change the condition of your if clause

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="slide">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.</div>
<div style="width:350px; background:#ccc;">Slide demo
<br/>Slide demo
<br/>Slide demo
<br/>Slide demo
<br/>Slide demo
<br/>Slide demo
<br/>Slide demo
<br/>Slide demo
<br/>Slide demo
<br/>Slide demo
<br/>
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var h = $(".slide").height();
h = h - 15;
$(".slide").css('top', '-' + h + 'px');
$(".slide").click(function () {
    var cond = '-' + h + 'px';
    if ($(".slide").css('top').toLowerCase() == cond) {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            top: h + 'px'
        }, 800);
    } else {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            top: '-' + h + 'px'
        }, 800);
    }
 });
});
```

**LIVE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/DcWS2/615/

There were few missing minor syntax errors as well on your jsfiddle, i have corrected them as well.

Happy Coding:)